# Issue with MySQL Generated Columns

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Hello I am trying to make a alter an exsisting table to add a Generated columns which is the count of all the rows in another table(It will be a like system so I am going to do all the matching and "WHERE" once I get this to work)

I am currently using this.

`ALTER TABLE board ADD like_cnt INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (COUNT(*) FROM likes) NOT NULL;`

But it gives me this error

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM likes) NOT NULL' at line 1

I am using WAMP and it has SQL version 5.7.24
Is this not possible or am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

There are limits in [GENERATED COLUMNS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) notably 'Subqueries are not permitted'

Comment: use a `SELECT COUNT(*)` when needed. As this can be slow on large tables maybe [information_schema.tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tables-table.html) is sufficient.

Comment: Ok thank you, I was trying to avoid that but I guess I have no choice